# Store a sensitive ini file (for PHPMailer credentials) in inetpub but outside of wwwroot in IIS - is it "public"?

Tags: php, iis, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails in PHP using SMTP with username & password authorization.

It works well, but I am concerned about hard coding the SMTP username & password in the php file.

Other threads on Stack Overflow have suggested "storing the username & password in an 'ini' file outside of the web server / document root"

So I've stored it in inetpub, but before wwwwroot. Eg. E:\inetpub\smtp.ini

Where as my websites are stored in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\exampleWebsite

My question is: Is my smtp.ini file stored in a 'non-public' area? In other words, if a website user can access wwwroot, can they also access a file in inetpub? Or is there a better folder / sub folder I should be storing it in?

My PHP code is as follows:

```
$path = realpath('/inetpub/smtp.ini');
$config = parse_ini_file($path, true);
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'outlook.office365.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = $config['smtp']['un'];
$mail->Password = $config['smtp']['pw'];
// ... rest of mail function ...
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is safe: the file is outside the web root and so has no external URL (assuming your server doesn't allow silly things like letting relative URLs go out of the web root like `../../smtp.ini`). You could protect it further by making it render to nothing, for example by adding a line like this at the start and then saving it as a `.php` file:

```
;<?php return false;
```

This looks like a harmless comment to an ini-file parser, but will produce a blank page if accessed as a PHP file.